# SSIS Flat file source records by column

Tags: ssis

Working with a flat file source that is records by columns - not rows... Suggestion on pulling the data.  Is fixed length with repeating field names.
PersonID     19
LastName     Doe
FirstName    John

PersonID     20
LastName     Brown
FirstName    Charlie

Comment: If it is the same order with a space, you can import it like that into a SQL table and then use SQL to convert every 4 rows to columns (including the blank one).  or use C# task to loop through the file line by line, and put each line into an object by line number in the file.  So have a loop and every 4 lines add a new item to your person object.

Comment: Just do it. What have you done so far? Describe what is the problem.

Comment: I don't see a question in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply Brad.  Example was simplified actual situation had 40+ fields. I ended up using a script component to create a pipe delimited string that was returned on the final field in the record - then conditional split to pull out only records that had the returned string - then sent to a new flat file destination.

```
string oRecord = "";
...
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
if (Row.dField.Trim() == "PersonID") /* first field in record */
{
oRecord = Row.dValue;
}
else
{
oRecord = oRecord + "|" + Row.dValue;
if (Row.dField.Trim() == "FirstName")  /* last field - send string back */
{
Row.OutRecord = oRecord;
}
}
}
```